# How to publish Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app to Windows Phone store?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

I created Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app, and I can't to upload it into WP store. I want to use `Create App Packages` tool in Visual Studio 2013 Professional, but it's impossible for Silverlight apps. I read many guides on [dev.windows.com](http://dev.windows.com). It's necessary to upload only `.appx`, `.appxbundle` or `.appxupload` files, but I have `.xap` file only in `Bin\ARM\Release` folder. May anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm having the same problem, which I just solved.
WP8.1 Silverlight application may not be packaged with the "Create App Packages" tool, so you have to perform several operations manually.

The process is described on msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn655122%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- First you have to start the submission of the app on your msdn dashboard.
- From here, you'll get some informations, such as reserved application name, and several IDs that you have to edit into both WMAppManifest.xml and Package.appxmanifest
- Then you can deploy your app (or run the emulator for release)
- This last step will create the package you can upload.

Comment: After manually changing the values what need to be done after that? I mean how to create package " This last step will create the package you can upload."

Comment: After changing the values to be build project ( configuration - release and ARM). In folder Bin\ARM\Release your .xap