# Publish windows phone 8 silverlight app

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-silverlight

I am having windows phone 8 silverlight app. I need to publish it on Windows store. Can you please provide or explain step by step guide to publish this app in store.

Stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254553/how-to-publish-windows-phone-8-1-silverlight-app-to-windows-phone-store) discussed already. But after changing the values in files manually what need to do after tha?

I followed the steps mention [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/749991/How-to-Publish-your-Windows-Phone-Application-on-t), but i am getting certification issue after submitting app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Windows App certification kit** is very nice utility. Before publishing app use this app for analysis. When i run analysis of my **XAP** file using this utility, I found that i was using some default images that was main issue in certification failure. Now i am updating that. And will let you if this works or not.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a guide](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/publish) to publishing applications in Windows Store. Important -Silverligth app supported only Windows Phone and not supported Windows 8 and Windows 10. For supported Windows RT you need to make [migration to universal app](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/12/17/bring-your-windows-phone-silverlight-apps-to-windows-runtime-xaml-prepare-for-universal-app-development-in-windows-10/).

Comment: In this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254553/how-to-publish-windows-phone-8-1-silverlight-app-to-windows-phone-store. They told about manually changes in values. But what to do after that. Please see my latest edits.

Comment: After changing the values to be build project ( configuration - release and ARM). In folder Bin\ARM\Release your .xap.

Comment: I have published my app using above steps. Certification  failed error is coming on store dashboard. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What issue do you see?

Comment: Error: Certification failed

Comment: You can try to buil application for Windows Phone Silverligth 8 and publish. If problem exist you try to contact to support https://dev.windows.com/en-us/community/windows-app-support